# The authenticity of host '103.35.202.76 (103.32.202.71)' can't be established

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ ssh root@103.32.202.71  
The authenticity of host '103.35.202.76 (103.32.202.71)' can't be established.  
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:w9u+mNFvkMg8lNydqJ/ZT6tV0lX/pwGIf1rWfYW1w0s.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

What does this mean: `RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:`?

Why does this show up?

---

If I choose the yes then I get the below information:

```
Warning: Permanently added '103.35.202.76' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.  
Connection to 103.35.202.76 closed by remote host.  
Connection to 103.35.202.76 closed.
```

---

I searched Unix & Linux, and I found [How does SSH display the message "The authenticity of host .. can't be established"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132219/how-does-ssh-display-the-message-the-authenticity-of-host-cant-be-establish).

Testing in my terminal:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 4  
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"/dev/tty",'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any kind of secure connection, you not only want to know that your connection, once established, is private between the parties communicating as well as resistant to tampering, but you also want to know that you're talking to the endpoint you thought you were talking to in the first place. Cryptography is great at solving the first problem, but it doesn't solve the second one at all (although it provides tool to help solve it). You need a PKI to solve the second problem.

SSH doesn't have an elaborate PKI, neither the web of trust system popularized by PGP nor the top-down certification system popularized by HTTPS & SSL. As a result, it can't guarantee that the serve responding at the other end of a connection really was the one you tried to connect to. The connection might have been redirected at the TCP or IP level underneath the crypto without the crypto being able to notice.

So the first time you connect to any SSH server, it asks you to confirm, by external means, whether the fingerprint offered by the server indeed corresponds to the fingerprint of the server you intended to connect to. You can verify this securely out of band, or, of course, at your own risk, you can answer yes anyway and take your chances.

SSH *does* have a kind of mini-PKI: after the first time, it remembers the server's fingerprint, so that when you connect again to the same server it can check if it's the same one as before.

Comment: SSH is based on a TOFU principle, that is Trust On First Use, which gives TOFU. You have the warning the first time, and then you can choose to add the key to your local "key store" so that next time it will get accepted as is, and you will get a warning only if it changes (either due to an attack or the host having changed its key). There are other options, like storing the host key in a DNS record, type SSHFP. See the `ssh_config` option `VerifyHostKeyDNS`.